# De l'Hospital theorem Wazewski's proof

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if you know if there is an English version of Tadeusz Wazewski's proof of de l'Hospital's theorem which is available here in French : http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/mathbwn/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-pmfv47i1p9bwm

But (unfortunately) I don't speak French.

Comment: I can't seem to find one via google, what makes this proof more special than the ones you would find in English real analysis texts?

Comment: Its generality and that what is proven there is that $liminf \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \le liminf \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le limsup\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le limsup \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $

Comment: I used to know French. I'll see if I can translate it easily enough.